# Problem of "RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment"

Tags: python, anaconda

Any operation of conda like `conda install, conda update, conda remove`, etc.,  receive a result of error, saying

> "RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be
>   removed from conda's operating environment."

I almost tried every solution I searched from the internet but just couldn't fix it.
It's like a tumor and I just can't find the core problem.

Comment: Are you trying to change your base conda environment, or do you get this error even when operating on a new environment?

Comment: Yes, but then I got the same error in base conda environment either. And I finally unloaded them all and didn't take more time looking for the reason

Answer (score 4):

Try the these commands step by step
`conda uninstall setuptools` after that
`conda install setuptools` and then
`conda update setuptools`
restart anaconda and then enter these commands

`conda update --force conda` or `conda update conda` and then
`conda update anaconda`
again restart your anaconda

Comment: Thank you~  this might be a solution and my college helped me unload the whole anaconda before I conduct them...anyway, finally it got normal. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue as the original poster, and get the following when I try "conda uninstall setuptools" "PackagesNotFoundeError: The following packages are missing from the target environment: -setuptools".  I assumed I should just try installing setuptools but that also fails with the error "RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment." which is the original issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

A simple conda update --force conda may fix this issue and go roll!

```
 conda update --force conda
```

Source :[RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment.](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8903)

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the following code in Anaconda Powershell Prompt

`conda install --force -c anaconda git`